# Result of integer division (1/n) always rounded down to 0.000

Tags: c

I have written a simple program, that reads one integer `number` and prints: `1 / number`.

I do not understand why the output is always: `0.000`.

```
void main()
{
    int n = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    float f = 1 / n;
    printf("%f",f);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
f = 1.0 / n;
```

The `1/n` will be int that converted to float and assigned to f.

`int` value of `1 / n` is `0` for all `n > 1`.

`1.0 / n` will perform the calculation in float and `f` will be assigned the expected result.

Comment: down voted because - while correct of course - this is way harder to follow then the other answers

Answer (score 6):

Your (`1/n`)  returns an integer value!

You need to have at least one `float` value in division!

Change (`1 / n`) to (`1.0 / n`).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your problem is, that both of your paramaters are integers. Dividing them will always yield an integer.

Try something like:

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
float f=1.0f/n;      // n will be converted to type: float
```

OR alternatively to read in a float.

```
float n;
scanf("%f",&n);
float f=1/n;         // 1 will be converted to type: float
```

Comment: Even if one number is float then that is enough!So your code has some redundant portions

Comment: @Rahul Jha you are right. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

 void main(  )
{
  float f = 0.0;
  float n = 0.0;
  scanf( "%f", &n );
  f = 1.0 / n;
  printf( "    %5.5f     ", f );
  getch(  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps you should just "cast" the operation like this

float f = (float)1 / n;
This will work!!!